# Problem with folder name in document library web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, folder, modern-pages

We've created folders in a document library to show on pages.

Steps taken

- Create a new page
- Add document library web part
- Select the document library
- Fill in the folder name

More often than not the folder name is recognized (the Apply button lights up) but when we click the Apply button it doesn't actually apply the change and clears out the Folder name field in the web part properties pane.

Usually, after several attempts it eventually works.

- I have not been able to discover a pattern as to when it starts working
- We haven't done anything permission related
- Literally working with a blank page, just containing a text web part
- Checking in powershell using Resolve-PnPFolder -SiteRelativePath simply resolves the folder without issue

Does anyone recognize this? I would greatly appreciate any help in solving this issue!

Edit: see screencapture below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce your issue per my test.

I add the document library web part in the home page, then fill in the folder name> click Apply, the folder name missing, however the document view will show the files in this folder.

[image]

When try to edit the web part again, the folder name is shown in the propertity panel.

For your issue, please add more document library web parts to compare if the issue happens occasionally.

Comment: Thanks Julie, I have added a similar gif to my opening post to illustrate the issue. First I try to type manually, then I copy the folder name from library web part. All won't work!

Comment: Whether adding any document library all occur the same issue? Please try different modern page, document library, even or another site to compare the result. You could also clear the browser cache, open the site in inprivate mode to check the result.If all above don't work for you, we suggest you raise a tickt to Microsft.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is causing my company major issues trying to set up pages for new hub deployment. Unbelievable bug form MS. One trick for us is to paste into folder name field and then tab to basically trick the folder name into sticking but this only works some of the time.